# Updated By column in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have  a grid view which is bound to an ObjectDataSource. After users have finished updating their data, I would like to put their username or userid in the UpdatedBy column to keep track who has updated what record. The UpdatedBy column could be hidden or readonly on the page so users can't just put any text in there.

Here is my UpdatedBy field:

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedBy" HeaderText="Updated By" SortExpression="UpdatedBy" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Updated By">
        <asp:itemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUpdatedBy" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("UpdatedBy") %>' Width="30" ></asp:Label>
        </asp:itemTemplate>
        <asp:editItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUpdatedBy" runat="server" CssClass="Gridview_EditItem" Text='<% #Bind("UpdatedBy") %>' Width="30" ></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:editItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I put updating code in RowUpdating event, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
protected void gvProductQuery_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow gr = gvProductQuery.Rows[e.RowIndex];
   TextBox tb = gr.FindControl("txtUpdatedBy") as TextBox;
   tb.Text = cUser.DomainLogin;
}
```

The tb is Null in the above code. Please help. Or is there an easier way to do this? I'm using VS2012

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this out :

```
protected void gvProductQuery_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   gvProductQuery.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
   gvProductQuery.DataBind();
}

protected void gvProductQuery_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = gvProductQuery.Rows[gvLevels.EditIndex];
   TextBox tb = row.FindControl("txtUpdatedBy") as TextBox;
   tb.Text = cUser.DomainLogin;
}
```

Comment: That row.FindControl("txtUpdatedBy") still returns null. I have also try to run through the row.Controls collection to see all the controls' ID and they are all null. If I look at the controls' UniqueID, they are a series like this ctl00$FeaturedContent$gvProductQuery$

Comment: No, I have not defined RowEditing event.

Comment: It still returns null. However, I notice the UpdatedBy column is not bound or at least it doesn't show the data or turn to the textbox in editing mode like other editItemTemplate fields. Can you spot an error some where? I also update my original databinding to include the default binding that works. The default UpdatedBy does show as an textbox

Comment: Ok. After deleted the UpdatedBy itemTemplate and recreated it. I was able to put the cUser.DomainLogin to the textbox based on the suggested code. However, it does not update the cell (I believe) as the value passed into the Update method of the datasource is still the old value. Any idea why?